# Iterate over list of dictionaries and find matching elements from a list and append value of matching key to defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a list of dictionaries. Let's call it: `list_of_dict`. The dictionaries in the list are in the form:

```
{'a' : 1,
'b' : 5,
'c' : 3,
'd' : 6}
```

and

```
{'a' : 3,
'f' : 2,
'g' : 1,
'h' : 3,
'i' : 5,
'j' : 3}
```

I have another list called `list_to_match` which only holds some letters: `['a', 'f', 'x']`

I need to iterate over `list_of_dict` and find the keys that match with the element in the list and append the values to a an empty defaultdict of list items. If not found, append 0 to the list.

The `defaultdict` is initialized as:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

I want the eventual defaultdict to look like:

```
{'a' : [1, 3],
'f' : [0, 2],
'x' : [0, 0]}
```

So far, I have:

```
for ld in list_of_dict:
    for match in list_to_match:
        for k, v in ld.items():
            d[match].append(v)
    d[match].append(0)
```

Now all of this works apart from the last line because obviously, match does not exist in that scope.
Now, all I get in the defaultdict is:

```
{'a' : [1, 3],
'f' : [2]}
```

The 0 is missing and so is x. How do I fix it?

Comment: So 0 stands for not found?

Comment: correct, but would rather append `0` than None or something like that.

Comment: The value of 'f' is 2 in the dictionary but 5 in the output is that correct?

Comment: nope, my bad. fixing it.

Comment: what is collections?

Comment: @RileyHughes collections is a python datatype. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, no need to use defaultdict:

```
list_of_dict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 5,
                 'c': 3,
                 'd': 6}, {'a': 3,
                           'f': 2,
                           'g': 1,
                           'h': 3,
                           'i': 5,
                           'j': 3}]

list_to_match = ['a', 'f', 'x']

d = {}
for match in list_to_match:
    for ld in list_of_dict:
        d.setdefault(match, []).append(ld.get(match, 0))

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': [1, 3], 'x': [0, 0], 'f': [0, 2]}
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{i: [j[i] if i in j else 0 for j in list_of_dict] for i in list_to_match}
```

Yields:

```
{'a': [1, 3], 'f': [0, 2], 'x': [0, 0]}
```

Even simpler:

```
{i: [j.get(i, 0) for j in list_of_dict] for i in list_to_match}
```

Comment: `j[i] if i in j else 0` is the same as `j.get(i, 0)`, which is more readable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can just do:

```
for m in list_to_match:
    d[m] = [ld.get(m, 0) for ld in list_of_dict]
print(d)
#defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 3], 'f': [0, 2], 'x': [0, 0]})
```

This would also work for a regular dictionary if you didn't want to use a `defaultdict`.