# How to search items in dictionary using list of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, text-analysis

I have a dictionary with keys and values called 'd'. I have another list of strings that I have to find values from the dictionary called list_to_find. Here is my code.

```
def getKeysByValues(dictOfElements, listOfValues):
  p = {}
  for match in dictOfElements:
   for ld in listOfValues:
     p.setdefault(match, []).append(ld.get(match, 0))
  return  p

ObtainedData = getKeysByValues(d,list_to_find)
```

The error I am getting is **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'**

My dictionary looks like this
[image]
Also my list_to_find looks like this.
[image]

My expected result would contain matched words with its values- ObtainedData : {'1st':'first','4th':'fourth'....}
How should I solve this? please help!!
I have tried to implement using this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977459/iterate-over-list-of-dictionaries-and-find-matching-elements-from-a-list-and-app)

However, I am not being to able to get the result and understand the error.

Comment: Your code is confusing. What do you want the result to look like exactly?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `dictOfElements & listOfValues`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to search the keys or the values?

Comment: @Rakesh, I have kept the images of how my dictionary and listofValues looks like. I want a result with the matched words from list_to_find with the dictionary and its value. For example, if my list_to_find contains "1st","4th", the result should be list of matched words with both keys and values: "1st: first, 4th: fourth".

Comment: Your dictionary contains many nan values. You cannot retrieve appropriate key if you have multiple keys that have the same value in your dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posted in this not entirely clear what you want to do.

This code below assigns values from your first dictionary (named d) to the list elements that are used as keys in a new dictionary. All of the list elements must be contained within d.

```
import numpy as np

d = {
'1st': ['first'],
'4th': ['fourth'],
'c': [np.nan],
'd': [np.nan],
'e': [np.nan],
'f': [np.nan],
'g': [np.nan]
}

l = ['1st', '4th']

new_d = {}

for i in l:
  new_d[i] = ''.join(d[i])

print(new_d)
#{'1st': 'first', '4th': 'fourth'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 'listOfValues' is a list and when iterating it using for loop the 'ld' already contains the value.
`ld.get()` is getting called on a string, i.e. the values of the list_to_find.

Hence the error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: How should I get the output as the matched words from list_to_find with the dictionary and its value? For example, if my list_to_find contains "1st","4th", the result should be a list of matched words with both keys and values: "1st: first, 4th: fourth"

Comment: can you please add an example of what you need. You can edit the question with these details